# What is the directory TexStudio puts generated PDF files to?

Tags: texstudio, output, directory

I'm using [TexStudio](http://www.texstudio.org/) and I'm having trouble finding the directory into which PDF files are being generated to.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: AFAIK, the PDF is generated in the same directory as the corresponding TeX file. Check the `.log` file, if there are errors that prevent the generation of the  `.pdf` file.

Answer (score 7):

As Heiko mentioned, the PDF is always generated in the same directory as its `.tex` file. There are 3 scenarios:

- The PDF is *not generated* at all due to some error in the document.
- You are compiling a `.tex` file that has been saved at least once before.
- You are compiling a `.tex` file that has *not* been saved before.

For the first case, you would have to provide more concrete information regarding your actual document for us to be of any help. (though I doubt that you're in this situation.)

For the second and third cases, you may follow the steps below to find the location of the generated PDF. As far as I know, these steps are the same regardless of your OS.

1. Go ahead and compile your document (<kbd>F1</kbd>, for example). Note the name of your document stated in the message at the bottom:

[image: message 1]

or

[image: message 2]

(Note that this step is not entirely necessary, I'm just highlighting one place you can find the name of the PDF generated in the TeXstudio UI. If the name is some `texstudio_xxxxxx`, then you are in situation 3.)

2. Open up the external PDF viewer (if it's not already default). This button can be found on the toolbar of the embedded viewer.

[image: external]

3. Now this is where your mileage may vary. Depending on which PDF viewer you have, this may or may not be an option. Here I show the case for SumatraPDF, a free PDF viewer. I imagine the case is similar for other PDF viewers.

   **SumatraPDF.**  Navigate to the document properties. `File` -> `Properties`. The file directory will be stated in the `File` name (see red box).

[image: sumatra]

You won't get the eyes of course. `:)`